# Post to me/feed as myself not app

Tags: post, facebook-wall

Is there a way to post to user wall as the user itself not an application, tried lots of things. One way is to use share, but it doesn't let to share app with right content in it.
Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all to do with the access_token being used. If the access_token you're using was issued to the application, then posts to /me/feed will go the applications wall, and be written by the application - it sounds like this is what's happening to you.

As yourself, you need to request an access token and authorize your app to post to your wall on your behalf. The necessary documentation is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Since you want the app to be able to post to your wall, you'll need it to ask you for the publish_stream [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) in within the scope, but since you've managed to get your app posting to its own wall as itself you've probably figured that part out already.